# Is there a way in javascript to identify when I mouse over the same element and when on a different?

Tags: javascript

I have a time variable that updates and want to restart its value only when you mouse over on a different element, if you hover on the same element it should keep updating. How should I approach this? Here's part of the code:

```
// Change shaders
function changeShader() {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.caption');

  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {

      if (you hovered on the same element) {
        console.log('you moused over the same element');
      } else {
        console.log('you moused over on a different element');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Before your cursor goes over another element, it would have already left the previous element. So I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here. Can you give us a concrete implementation of the logic you're trying to write? This feels like an XY problem to me.

Comment: @Terry sorry for my terrible explanation. Hope this could give more insight:

I am showing different image textures using a three.js scene when the mouse goes over different elements or captions. As soon as the mouse enters the element a time variable (set to 0) updates 60 times per second using requestAnimationFrame. This variable helps me create different shader animations for the textures. What I want is to restart the time value to 0 only when the mouse goes over a different element, if the mouse is moved over the same element, the time should continue updating. Same with all elements.

Comment: why not just reset it when it leaves the current element ?

Comment: I would use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, as [they don't bubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) and so are more intuitive to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save last hovered dom and check if it's the same:

---

```js
function changeShader() {
  let last_hover;
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.caption');

  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      if (last_hover == this) {
        console.log('you moused over the same element');
      } else {
        console.log('you moused over on a different element');
      }
      last_hover = this;
    });
  });
}

changeShader()
```

```css
.caption, .no-hover{
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="caption">I am Caption 1</div>
<div class="caption">I am Caption 2</div>
<div class="caption">I am Caption 3</div>
<div class="caption">I am Caption 4</div>
<div class="caption">I am Caption 5</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do so dynamically with JavaScript.  In this example, the code assigns a handler  to the onmouseover event of each element, in this case each element is a button.

```js
var flags = new Array(2);
flags[0] = 0;
flags[1] = 0;
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

    for (let i = 0, max = buttons.length; i < max; i++) {
          let temp = i;
          buttons[temp].onmouseover= function(){
               console.log("Moused over this button " + buttons[temp].id + " " + flags[temp]++ + "x  before." );
    if ((flags[temp] == 2)) {
        this.onmouseover = null;
        alert("Done documenting bbutton " + buttons[temp].id);
     }
};  
}// end for
```

```html
<style>
#a {
background: #000;
color: lime;
}
#b {
background: #000;
color: cyan;
}
#a:hover,#b:hover {
background: #600;
color: #ffdede;
}
</style>
<div><button id="a">Button A</button>
<button id="b">Button B</button></div>
```

By setting each button with a unique id attribute, it uses that value to distinguish which button is being moused over.

Note: the CSS is strictly optional -- just wanted to enhance the visuals.